# Singe SQL Query to retrieve fields from 2 different table.

Tags: sql

Trying to explain my Question:
Say, Table A contains ID,Number,Location.

Table B contains Option 1,Option 2.

---

I want to write a single query that would select ID, Number & Option 1 from the Table A and Table B.

(At present I am doing something like:

SELECT ID FROM [A]
SELECT Option 1 FROM [B]

)

Comment: How does table A relate to table B?  You could do a normal Cartesian join (select f.id, s.option1 from A f, B s), but there's no indication that's what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Number, B.Option1
FROM TableA as A, TableB as B 
WHERE A.id = B.id;
```

This Part sets an alias for the table so that you don't have type in the full table name all the time:

```
TableA as A
TableB as B
```

This part is the relationship between table A and B.

```
WHERE A.id = B.id;
```

Consider reading SQL table relationships http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships/